Element's attribute window
For example, when I add an element in a layer (point or linestring), the drawing stop with right taste of mouse, open the window of the attribute element's table: if you have to add multiple time elements, this table always change the position, in a down direction, until it go down of the screen, so you have to mannually drag it up.
Is there a method to "lock" it in the initial  position?
I mean not to hook on side but to have all time the same automatic opening position.
